# Generate PKCS#8 private key with openssl

Tags: openssl, rsa, pkcs#1, pkcs#8

Is it possible to use `openssl` to generate a PKCS#8 private key directly, or do I have to first generate a PKCS#1 key with `genrsa` and then convert it?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can do this directly:

```
$ openssl genpkey -out rsakey.pem -algorithm RSA -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

See the man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-genpkey.html

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say that it uses PKCS#8 ?

Comment: @KishanB Regardless of the documentation, I've tried this myself and the encoding *is* PKCS #8.

Comment: A rather baffling update to the above comment - specifying -outform DER doesn't just change from PEM to DER, it also changes the DER from PKCS #8 to PKCS #1.

Comment: Thanks, that's very valuable information. Question, is it possible to generate PKCS#8 pair with one line command? I need to send public key to the receiver. I looked into the MAN but can't find related information.

Comment: PKCS#8 is a format for private keys. I guess what you want is a PKCS#8 file for the private key and (something like) a SubjectPublicKeyInfo (SPKI) file for the public key. You can't generate both of those in a single command, but you can generate the SPKI file from the PKCS#8 file: `openssl pkey -in rsakey.pem -pubout -out rsapubkey.pem`